# Copy constructor should copy *string values

Tags: c++, string, copy-constructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a class:

```
class BankAccount
{
    string *name;
    string *number;
public:
    BankAccount(BankAccount &);
    ~BankAccount();
};

BankAccount::BankAccount(BankAccount &account)
{
    string nameS = account.name;
    this->name = new string(nameS);
    this->number = new string(account.*number);
}
```

I would like to that my copy constructor copy the strings (not the pointers, but strings pointed by pointers) to new object. I tried two different methods but I've never succeeded.

Compiler messages:

> `conversion from 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' to non-scalar type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' requested`
>
> `'((BankAccount*)this)->BankAccount::number' cannot be used as a member pointer, since it is of type 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}'`

Comment: This class design is insane. Don't use pointers or `new`, just have `string` members.

Comment: What's wrong with just using std::string members?  If you did that, all of the problems in the code will go away.

Comment: `string nameS = *(account.name);` and `this->number = new string(*(account.number));`

Comment: If that's posible I'd like to get answer using pointers, because class design is not my idea, it's task for uni.

Comment: thanks @sgar91 That is solution, what I was looking for!

Comment: Did your school talk about copy constructors?  Assignment operators?  Destructors?  The rule of 3?  Exception safety when doing copy assignment?  Copy-swap idiom?  I seriously doubt it.  So I don't see why things like this are even assigned, unless you had a session on these topics in class.

Comment: @pw94 - Your class has no assignment operator.  I can easily break it with a 2 line main() program, even with the changes that sgar91 gave you.  Given that it can be easily broken, what have you learned?  How to make broken programs?  You're supposed to be producing *working* C++ programs, not buggy ones.  Using std::string removes *all* the bugs you are seeing.  That's why these assignments, when not given the proper amount of discussion time in class, are hindrances to learning C++ than being helpful.  You create buggy programs, all the while thinking the programs are "good".

Comment: Why don't you either just store strings (instead of pointers) or use automatic pointers instead of classic ones? Btw, shouldn't the copy constructor accept a const reference? (Was originally an answer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the other comments and answers, in this case there is no need to use pointers as instance variables. You would be better off just making the instance variables actual strings. But just to explain your problem:

```
string nameS = account.name;
```

account.name is a pointer to a string, so you need this:

```
string nameS = *account.name;
```

In this statement:

```
this->number = new string(account.*number);
```

You are dereferencing incorrectly. It should be:

```
this->number = new string(*account.number);
```

Answer (score 2):

The class BankAccount should probably just contain string objects rather then pointers to strings

```
class BankAccount
{
    string name;
    string number;
};
```

Edit: as pointed out by other users, you now no longer need to write a copy constructor or destructor as std strings take care of themselves

Comment: The copy constructor should actually look like this:

Comment: i.e., because the members are classes which take care of themselves, you don't need a copy constructor (or destructor)

Comment: @juanchopanza I disagree. The current example is using assignment inside the constructor instead of using the initialization list of the constructor. Some info about this on the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html). Besides that, TooTone is right that in this case the copy-constructor isn't even needed.

Comment: Changed it to use the initialization list.

Comment: @ParvusM the point is that the copy constructor isn't necessary when `string` objects are contained. Nor is the destructor. (juanchopanza's comment indicated that the copy constructor should look like "", i.e. it shouldn't exist.)

Comment: @HarryRose sorry to labour the point, but you really ought to change your answer to remove the copy constructor and destructor as they are unnecessary.

Comment: @ParvusM My point is that there shouldn't be any user provided copy constructor in this case. Even after the changes, this one is broken because it takes a non-const reference, so it can't bind to temporaries.